# Running a python script at a fixed time everyday with crontab

Tags: python, python-3.x, cron

First of all, I have tried every method suggested on this site and others but I still can't get it to work.
My python script is located in my home folder. It imports modules like requests, time, and other third party modules. It works fine with command line.
But it doesn't work with crontab. I think the problem is that when it's run from cron, import doesn't work and the script fails.
**crontab:**

```
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
SHELL=/bin/bash
PYTHONPATH=/home/chanzerre:/usr/lib64/python35.zip:/usr/lib64/python3.5:/usr/lib64/python3.5/plat-linux:/usr/lib64/python3.5/lib-dynload:/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages:/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages
* * * * * /home/chanzerre/script.py
```

My Python script's structure:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.5
import requests as req
import time
from pprint import pprint
# third party imports here

#code here
```

Can anyone help?
Would give more details if needed.

P.S.
Please, don't mark it as dupe, because I have tried all methods suggested in the similar questions asked by others and for the love of my life, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Show your crontab statement

Comment: @joelgoldstick I edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set all the environment variables that your script needs in order to run? If not, it won't work.For example,if you are running that script behind a proxy server, and the proxy variable is not set, it won't work.
Set your proxy variable in crontab or in the python script itself and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making your `script.py` an executable file? Just typing the path to a Python file won't run the script. You need to add a shebang to your file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

and then make it executable:

```
$ mv /home/chanzerre/script.py /home/chanzerre/script
$ chmod +x /home/chanzerre/script
```

then your crontab becomes

```
* * * * * /home/chanzerre/script
```

Try that and see if it runs your file.

Comment: Have you tried and just made the code in the file do something really simple? Like write `"ran crontab"` to a file in your home directory? I guess I'm just wondering if it has ever worked or what would be evidence that it did work.

Comment: Something simple works. For example, 
    `print('hello')` works before imports.

Comment: What about `print("hello"); import requests; [more imports]; print("End")`?

Comment: It only prints hello, nothing after that.

Comment: How did you install those libraries? I'm wondering if you installed them with a different python executable than the one that you have in the shebang of your current script. What does `which python` show?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128544/discussion-between-gr1zzly-be4r-and-chanzerre).